# Compartir en instagram via enlace web

Tags: html, instagram-api, instagram

Es posible compartir una imagen y un texto en instagram via web.

Ejemplo: En facebook tienes el plugin social que te lo permite => [boton social](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)

Existe en instagram una forma mediante un enlace o mediante la api de hacer esto?

Comment: En teoría, el contenido que compartes en Instagram debe ser propio y original, por lo que un botón social de Instagram (en plan Facebook Share) no tendría sentido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actualmente no existe una herramienta de gestión de Redes Sociales que pueda publicar contenido previamente programado directamente en tu cuenta en Instagram. 
Nno es culpa de las herramientas sino que **Instagram no lo permite** debido limitaciones en su API (interfaz de programación de aplicaciones).

Instagram no quiere mostrarte todo lo que sucede en ella por lo que su API solo responde a las solicitudes permitidas.

Existen algunas aplicaciones que han sometido la API de Instagram a procesos de ingeniería inversa para lograr publicar de manera automática por los usuarios... pero ...
**Hacerlo representa una grave violación a las políticas de Instagram**, la cual indica, “No debes acceder a la API privada de Instagram mediante métodos distintos de los permitidos por Instagram.” https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511